# Batch File- Delete Folder contents and the parent folder

Tags: batch-file

I make the following directory at the beginning of my BATCH FILE to store temporary content:

> "%userprofile%\Downloads\VersionCheckWillDelete"

I wish to remove this folder and all of its contents.

The following removes only the data in the folder but not the folder itself:

```
RD /S /Q "%userprofile%\Downloads\VersionCheckWillDelete"
```

EDIT: Turns out that it isn't deleting it because the BATCH file is still using it. I have considered POWERSHELL being still open and trying to kill it but it isn't open. How do I close it in the background. It doesn't need to be running anymore?
"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

THE FOLLOWING IS MY CODE:

```
 @echo off

:version_chk

SET USER_VER=1.1.2-RC

ECHO * * * * * * * * * * * * *
ECHO CHECKING FOR UPDATES...
ECHO * * * * * * * * * * * * *

cd "%userprofile%\Downloads"
    mkdir "%userprofile%\Downloads\VersionCheckWillDelete"

cd "%userprofile%\Downloads\VersionCheckWillDelete"

powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest https://github.com/KSanders7070/AIRPORT_ALIAS_CREATION/blob/master/Version_Check -OutFile 'version_check.HTML'"

findstr "VERSION-" "version_check.HTML" >> "GitHub_Version.txt"

cd "%userprofile%\Downloads\VersionCheckWillDelete"

for /f "delims=" %%x in (GitHub_Version.txt) do set GH_VER_STRING_ORIGINAL=%%x

for /f "tokens=2 delims=<" %%x in ("%GH_VER_STRING_ORIGINAL%") do set GH_VER_STRING_FIRST_HALF=%%x

SET "GH_VER=%GH_VER_STRING_FIRST_HALF:*VERSION-=%"

if %USER_VER% == %GH_VER% GOTO NORMAL_PROCESS

:UPDATE_AVAIL

CLS

START "" "https://github.com/KSanders7070/AIRPORT_ALIAS_CREATION/releases"

ECHO * * * * * * * * * * * * *
ECHO     UPDATE AVAILABLE
ECHO * * * * * * * * * * * * *
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO GITHUB VERSION: %GH_VER%
ECHO YOUR VERSION:   %USER_VER%
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO PLEASE CLOSE THIS BATCH FILE AND GO DOWNLOAD THE MOST RECENT UPDATE AVAILABLE:
ECHO.
ECHO https://github.com/KSanders7070/AIRPORT_ALIAS_CREATION/releases
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO OR YOU MAY PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE USING THIS VERSION.
ECHO.
ECHO.

cd "%userprofile%\Downloads"
rd /S /Q "%userprofile%\Downloads\VersionCheckWillDelete\"
PAUSE

:NORMAL_PROCESS

CLS

cd "%userprofile%\Downloads"
rd /S /Q "%userprofile%\Downloads\VersionCheckWillDelete\"

ECHO Your BATCH file is the most up to date version.

PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:
Removing the START "URL" line allowed the BATCH to delete the folder. Not sure why it was dependent on Chrome but it solves the issue. So, placing the RD command before the START "" command makes everything work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove directory you need to use this command.

```
rmdir path
del -f path
```

Comment: That is not for Windows cmd.exe.

Comment: 'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

There was absolutely no reason to change directory to `%UserProfile%\Downloads\VersionCheckWillDelete`, in the first instance. Additionally, there's probably no reason to use the `Downloads` location when that is one of the purposes of the `%Temp%` directory. Regardless of which you choose, you only really need it for the `version_check.html` file you're parsing, so why not put it directly into the chosen location, instead of creating a new directory and removing it afterwards. *(That way you only need to delete the file if necessary, I would expect that on each run, the file would be overwritten anyhow)*.

That said, this is probably how I would do what you're doing:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
Set "USER_VER=1.1.2-RC"
Echo * * * * * * * * * * * * *
Echo CHECKING FOR UPDATES...
Echo * * * * * * * * * * * * *
Echo(
If Not Exist "%UserProfile%\Downloads\VersionCheckWillDelete\" MD "%UserProfile%\Downloads\VersionCheckWillDelete"
%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "Invoke-WebRequest -URI \"https://github.com/KSanders7070/AIRPORT_ALIAS_CREATION/blob/master/Version_Check\" -OutFile \"%UserProfile%\Downloads\VersionCheckWillDelete\version_check.html\""
For /F "Tokens=3 Delims=><" %%G In ('%__AppDir__%findstr.exe ">VERSION-[0-9]" "version_check.html"') Do For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=-" %%H In ("%%G") Do Set "GH_VER=%%I"
RD "%UserProfile%\Downloads\VersionCheckWillDelete"
If "%USER_VER%" == "%GH_VER%" Echo Your batch file is the most up to date version.& GoTo Continue
ClS
Echo * * * * * * * * * * * * *
Echo     UPDATE AVAILABLE
Echo * * * * * * * * * * * * *
Echo(
Echo GITHUB VERSION: %GH_VER%
Echo YOUR VERSION:   %USER_VER%
Echo(
Echo YOU ARE NOT USING THE LATEST VERSION!
Echo(
Echo 1. DOWNLOAD THE LATEST VERSION NOW
Echo 2. CONTINUE USING THIS OUTDATED VERSION
Echo(
%__AppDir__%choice.exe /C 12
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo Continue
Echo Your Web Browser will now open on the Releases page and this batch file will close.
%__AppDir__%timeout.exe /T 5
Start "" "https://github.com/KSanders7070/AIRPORT_ALIAS_CREATION/releases"
GoTo :EOF

:Continue
Echo(
Echo Continuing . . .
Pause
ClS
```

Comment: Please note @KSanders, that your current version is showing as `1.1.2-RCX`, not `1.1.2-RC`, so the script you've posted does not work with the current version. I would assume, in order for it to work, you'd need to provide a new version of the script with each release too. So please make sure you've taken account of that. Also because of the mismatch, please ensure that any modifications you're currently making are not for an older version, as opposed to the current one.

Comment: COMPO- Thank you for this restructure and please forgive the lateness of my reply, as I am new to this and did not consider the common etiquette for these type of forums.

I like how your code doesn't require the need for exporting the FINDSTR as a text file and all. I will be taking your advice about changing to the TEMP folder.

I have made a few changes to what you propose for reasons of continuity for my other BATCH file scripts along with small changes such as taking into account that the Version of a BAT might not start with a number.

Comment: Also, your Powershell webrequest did not like my variables for some reason so I have returned to using my powershell. If you have any suggestions about how to handle that in the future, I'm all ears! :D

I do have a certain satisfaction that the files my BAT processes create will be cleaned up so I think I am going to leave the RD there, unless you see any actual downside to this?

I have given you a special thanks in a remark at the beginning of the script and on this release of the BAT on GH.

Check out the new script here: https://github.com/KSanders7070/BATCH_FILE_VERSION_CHECK

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @KSanders. Could you expand upon what you mean by "webrequest did not like my variables", it may assist me, because the only variables used in that line are `%__AppDir__%`, which will always resolve to `%SystemRoot%\System32\ `, (or `%SystemRoor%\SysWOW64\ ` on a 64-bit system ran from a 32-bit `cmd.exe` instance) regardless of any changes to your environment variables, and `%UserProfile%` which you could allow `PowerShell` to expand, if you prefer, i.e. `$Env:UserProfile`. As for the `RD` command that's your decision, I left it in in the code above for you regardless.

Comment: When I take your line of code for PS and replace the exact URL with the variable for the URL, it returns the following error:

The string is missing the terminator: ".
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

Comment: Example: 
%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "Invoke-WebRequest -URI \"%GITHUB_VERSION_CHK_URL%" -OutFile \"%UserProfile%\Downloads\VersionCheckWillDelete\version_check.html\""

Comment: The following works: powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest %GITHUB_VERSION_CHK_URL% -OutFile 'version_check.HTML'"

Comment: You haven't used the same syntax as I did @KSanders. Assuming that `%GITHUB_VERSION_CHK_URL%` isn't enclosed with doublequotes, _(it shouldn't be)_, then the matching syntax would be: `%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "Invoke-WebRequest -URI \"%GITHUB_VERSION_CHK_URL%\" -OutFile \"%UserProfile%\Downloads\VersionCheckWillDelete\version_check.html\""`. Your example didn't escape the closing nested doublequote after the `-URI` path with a backslash.

Comment: you are very right. I used your code here and it worked. However, My code works too. What is the pro/con for using mine vs yours? Mine: powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest %GITHUB_VERSION_CHK_URL% -OutFile 'version_check.HTML'"